# How do I get Ruby to parse time as if it were in a different time zone?

Tags: ruby, timezone

I'm parsing something like this:

```
11/23/10 23:29:57
```

which has no time zone associated with it, but I know it's in the UTC time zone (while I'm not).  How can I get Ruby to parse this as if it were in the UTC timezone?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could just append the UTC timezone name to the string before parsing it:

```
require 'time'
s = "11/23/10 23:29:57"
Time.parse(s) # => Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 -0800 2010
s += " UTC"
Time.parse(s) # => Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 UTC 2010
```

Comment: Doh! I actually tried that and misinterpreted the result.  My bad.  Thanks.

Comment: Does not work in my case. `s="Fri Dec 3 17:05:41 2010 UTC"` will get parsed as local time and ignore the trailing `UTC`

Comment: This can't possibly be the best general case solution

Comment: Might work but it's not good engineering practice.

Answer (score 36):

credit from https://rubyinrails.com/2018/05/30/rails-parse-date-time-string-in-utc-zone/,

```
Time.find_zone("UTC").parse(datetime)
# => Wed, 30 May 2018 18:00:00 UTC +05:30
```

Comment: For the record this requires Rails (ActiveSupport at least)

Comment: There should really be a `TimeZone::UTC` constant so you don't have to find it via string name every time you want to use it!

Answer (score 26):

If your using rails you can use the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` helpers

```
current_timezone = Time.zone
Time.zone = "UTC"
Time.zone.parse("Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 2010") # => Tue, 23 Nov 2010 23:29:57 UTC +00:00
Time.zone = current_timezone
```

It is designed to have the timezone set at the beginning of the request based on user timezone.

Everything does need to have `Time.zone` on it, so `Time.parse` would still parse as the servers timezone.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Note: the time format you have above was no longer working, so I changed to a format that is supported.

Comment: If you don't want to change the whole Time.zone context, use ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('UTC').parse

Comment: @Jerph, your answer is definitely the best

Comment: @jerph your approach is much better, and actually thread safe.

Comment: With ActiveSupport::TimeZone you can even do it with a block (same as @jerph answer) : `Time.use_zone('UTC') { Time.zone.parse('Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 2010') }`

Answer (score 10):

If you are using ActiveSupport [from Rails, e.g], you can do this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["GMT"].parse("..... date string")
```

Answer (score 9):

Another pure Ruby (no Rails) solution if you don't want/need to load ActiveSupport.

```rb
require "time"

ENV['TZ'] = 'UTC'
Time.parse("2019/10/01 23:29:57")
#=> 2019-10-01 23:29:57 +0000
```

Comment: This is the best answer thus far. Pure Ruby, no fRails! thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Without rails dependencies: `Time` parses in local time but `DateTime` parses in UTC. Then you can transform it to a `Time` class if that's what you want:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.parse(string_to_parse).to_time
```

Answer (score 4):

An aliter to @Pete Brumm's answer without Time.zone set/unset

```
Time.zone.parse("Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 2010") + Time.zone.utc_offset
```