# How can I use Ruby to parse a time as though it is in a time zone I specify, with zone in the format America/Los_Angeles?

Tags: ruby, timezone

I want to be able to parse a Time from a string in Ruby (1.8.7), where the string does not contain any time zone information.  I would like to treat the string as though it were in any of a number of time zones specified in this type of format: 'America/New_York'.

Time string example:

```
'2010-02-05 01:00:01'
```

I have spent quite a while trying to figure this one out.

I did find a similar question, but its answer does not apply in my case: [How do I get Ruby to parse time as if it were in a different time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262550/how-do-i-get-ruby-to-parse-time-as-if-it-were-in-a-different-time-zone)

The problem with the above solution is that my time zones cannot all be represented in the 3-letter format supported by Time.parse (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/time/rdoc/classes/Time.html#M004931).

Is there a good way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Edit: Made my answer actually appear as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post with a stab at using that gem for my problem.

Comment: It's absurd to me that plain Ruby doesn't have a means of doing this.  It would be nice not to have to rely on a chunky Rails library/gem.  Not sure why the `tzinfo` gem wouldn't provide a way to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with using the tzinfo gem as suggested, though it seems rather complicated and unintuitive to me. As an end result I get the time parsed as though it were in the time zone I wanted, though represented by a Time object in UTC. I can also display it in the time zone I want using tzinfo's strftime:

```
jruby-1.6.1 :003 > time = '2010-05-01 01:00:00'
 => "2010-05-01 01:00:00" 
jruby-1.6.1 :004 > tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
 => #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/New_York> 
jruby-1.6.1 :005 > time += ' UTC'
 => "2010-05-01 01:00:00 UTC" 
jruby-1.6.1 :006 > time = Time.parse(time)
 => Sat May 01 01:00:00 UTC 2010 
jruby-1.6.1 :007 > time = tz.local_to_utc(time)
 => Sat May 01 05:00:00 UTC 2010 
jruby-1.6.1 :010 > tz.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', time)
 => "2010-05-01 01:00:00 EDT"
```

I believe this will suit my needs, but I wonder if I can get the Time to actually be in the timezone above (instead of just UTC).

Comment: While I think this code will work, might I suggest improving the organization?  Try setting up the tz object, and then the date, and then combining, instead of jumping back and forth between the two logic chains

Answer (score 11):

```
require 'active_support/all'
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('UTC').parse('2010-02-05 01:00:01')

puts time
puts time.in_time_zone('EST')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I needed to get unstuck, where I want to parse a string in a given timezone, and then convert to utc timestamp: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Pacific Time (US & Canada)').parse("May 12, 2015 10:27:48 AM").utc.to_i`

Comment: Thank you, I must have wasted 2 hours trying to sort out an ETL job that was generating wrong time records.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options the way I see it. On the one hand you could map the format you wish to use in an array (or any other structure you wish) to the 3-letter format used by Time.parse.

The other option is using the tzinfo gem as specified by my which seems to do the job quite nicely.

```
>> tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/New_York")
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/New_York>
>> tz.now
=> Thu Jul 07 16:29:13 UTC 2011
>> tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get("Europe/Rome")
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Rome>
>> tz.now
=> Thu Jul 07 22:30:03 UTC 2011
```

Comment: Yeah, this is close.  The trick is that I need to parse a date represented as a string.  I added an attempt at this in my post.