# In ruby parse a time in an arbitrary gmt offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, timezone

I'm running in Rails 3.2 and I can't figure out a nice way to parse a time that's given to me in an arbitrary time zone.

As an example this is the format I'm given in separate keys

```
{
  "start_date"=>"2013-04-24 13:00:00",
  "timezone"=>"America/Los_Angeles",
  "timezone_offset"=>"GMT-0700",
  ...
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615463/how-can-i-use-ruby-to-parse-a-time-as-though-it-is-in-a-time-zone-i-specify-wit) comes very close to answering it with:

```
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('UTC').parse('2010-02-05 01:00:01')
```

The problem is when I put in "America/Los_Angeles" as an argumento to `Timezone.new`, it spits out a timezone of GMT-8, I think due to DST changing. On the other hand, the data I receive defines the timezone offset from GMT. So for my example, the desired output is a timezone of GMT-7.

Is there any way to get the timezone if I know the gmt offset, instead of using the name of the timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[]` on `ActiveSupport::Timezone`, passing the gmt offset in hours as the argument.

As seen on [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-5B-5D):

`[](arg)`

> Locate a specific time zone object. If the argument is a
>   string, it is interpreted to mean the name of the timezone to locate.
>   If it is a numeric value it is either the hour offset, or the second
>   offset, of the timezone to find. (The first one with that offset will
>   be returned.) Returns nil if no such time zone is known to the system.

Code example:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/Los_Angeles"]                              
 => (GMT-08:00) America/Los_Angeles
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-8]                              
 => (GMT-08:00) America/Los_Angeles
```

So, what you would do is:

```
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-7].parse('2013-04-24 13:00:00')
```

However, be careful since an offset may be equivalent to more than one timezone, since many timezones can be on the same offset.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I knew it took strings, didn't know it also took offset times.